# Disabled (always-checked) checkbox values not being passed to next page

Tags: forms, checkbox

I have a set of checkboxes and have disabled few which I want to be always true and user can not unselect them. When I submit the form I am not getting the disabled checkboxes value. How to get this values

```
<? echo "<PRE>"; print_r($_POST);?>



<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="t[1]" value="1" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" />1
<input type="checkbox" name="t[2]" value="2" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" />2
<input type="checkbox" name="t[3]" value="3" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" />3
<input type="checkbox" name="t[4]" value="4" />4
<input type="checkbox" name="t[5]" value="5" />5
<input type="checkbox" name="t[6]" value="6" />6
<input type="checkbox" name="t[7]" value="7" />7    
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I Should get values 1,2,3 always and the values user selected if any

Comment: Why do you need them, if you know that they are checked?

Comment: disabled input elements are **not**, by standard, being sent via submit...

Comment: @entek, it might be useful to show pre-selected options to the user as part of UX design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a fact, disabled elements are *disabled* and will not be sent, as @BluesRockAddict already said. 
What you can do is using JavaScript for disallowing unchecking the checkbox. You might use something like this `<checkbox [...] onclick="return false" onkeydown="return false"`
But still, as you disable JavaScript, this will not work.

Answer (score 7):

For each disabled checkboxes use <input type="hidden" ... /> with the same name and value.

Answer (score 1):

For disabled checkboxes, the values will never be posted to the server. One possible workaround would be to add some javascript code that would enable disabled checkboxes upon submitting the form.